# Is SOH Gen 2 and LOH Same?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I have small confusion regarding GC Generation.

First of all I have following Idea about Heap. .NET Runtime has many heap but user memory mainly use SOH and LOH.

1. Now there are three Generation Gen 0 ,1 and 2.
2. Also if object size Greater then 85000 Byte then it moved to LOH.

So My Confusion is 
1. Is SOH devided into Three Generation Gen 0 , 1 and 2 ? 
2. LOH is different. 
OR 
Gen 2 of SOH and LOH are Same ?

Comment: Not the same.  Gen #2 consists of the heap segments that were once the gen #1 segment and got promoted because it filled up.  LOH is a separate heap for large objects.  Objects are never "moved" to the LOH, they get created there when they are big enough.

Comment: I have same thought. System.GC.GetGeneration Method create confusion for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official document from microsoft that made the confusion
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap
and here you can read simplier explanation:
https://dalisama.me/wtf-is-memory-management-and-garbage-collection-in-the-net

as you can see now, SOH and LOH are two different things. Since SOH has 3 generations: 0,1 and 2, that means that SOH 2 and LOH are two different things, and memory segments allocated to SOH gen 2 and LOH are different. SOH 2 allocates 'small' objects < 85 KB while LOH allocates large objects > 85KB.
The confusion comes into place because GC triggers full GC collect on all segments both soh and loh when either gen 2 or loh treshold had been reached. when soh gen 0 and soh gen 1 are collected - gen 2 and loh are not touched. but - they are not the same :)

Answer (score 0):

SOH is design for small and short live object
it move from gen 0 to gen 2(survive via GC), 
does not mean the object is large than 85k

If a object is large than 85k, it should be allocated to LOG directly, then it doesn't need to move for performance reason.